# would like to extract words from a path - powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am running a script in which has a path like below

- C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\logs\
- C:\Program Files\Atlassian\Confluence\logs\
- C:\Atlassian\ApplicationData\Bitbucket\log
- C:\Atlassian\bitbucket-backup-client-4.0.0\backups\

---

and want to extract words display it like

- Jira - Logs

  - list of files Not Deleted
  - list of files Deleted
- Confluence - Logs

  - list of files Not Deleted
  - list of files Deleted
- Bitbucket - Logs

  - list of files Not Deleted
  - list of files Deleted
- Bitbucket - Backups

  - list of files Not Deleted
  - list of files Deleted
- etc...

as it goes through various paths and does the work. I have the code for the not deleted files and deleted files...

just would like to capture earlier mentioned details and display it while it is doing the function.

part of PowerShell function where I am using
and capturing log using start-transcript - path "log path"

```
    if ($files.count -gt 0)
    {
    Write-Host "List of Files not deleted"
        for ($i= ($files.Count - $keep); $i -lt $Files.Length; 
$i++)
        {
            #$Files[$i]
            Write-output $files[$i].fullname
        }
    if (($files.Count - $keep) -gt 0) 
            {
        # reduce the array to contain only the number of files in $keep
        $files = $files | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First $keep
         Write-Output "------------------"
         Write-Output "List of Deleted Files from " 
         Write-output "------------------"
         Write-Output $files.FullName | format-table
         Write-output "------------------"
        #$date,"List of Files Deleted" $files.FullName | Add- Content -Path 'E:\backup\housekeep_log\Housekeep.log' #-verboes
        #$files | Remove-Item -Force
    }
    stop-transcript
```

Comment: Have managed to find the solution  to my query ..... thanks to other members post.. below is the solution I am using..
$path = "C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA\logs\"
$_foldername1 = $path.split("\")[-3]
$_foldername2 = $path.split("\")[-2]

Write-host $_foldername1 "-" $_foldername2 | Format-table

Comment: thanks @daniel for correcting... mistakes in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stored values in to a csv file...and called it through variable.

```
$config = Import-Csv -Path 'E:\Backup\Scripts\HousekeepConfig.csv'
 #Write-Output $Config
 $date = Get-Date  -Format "yyyMMdd_hhmmss"  
 Start-Transcript -Path E:\Backup\Housekeep_Log\Housekeep.log
  $oldpath = get-location
 foreach ($item in $config) 
  {
  Write-host $item.Name | Format-table
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be:

```
$caption = $path.Parent.Name + " - " + $path.Name
```

Comment: yes, that right... thanks. did another change... added those values into my main csv files where i am storing other things like path, file extensions etc.